# Stfrtime with 'D' inside String

Tags: python, pandas, string

How can you deal with a random string inside a datetime string when parsing using pandas?

I have some timestamps of the form

[image]

Which I try to match with this `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f'`

*(Why they have a 'D' instead of a 'T' is uncertain - they're not durations!)*

When I try to parse them using Pandas, I get this error

```
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
```

I am confident the dataset is consistent in form.

Is there a correct way to do this?

*I realise I can replace the 'D' with 'T' but keeping the original form of the data is crucial for this piece of work.*

Answer (score 1):

If need original form with `D` and type datetimes/Timestamp, it is impossible in python.

If need convert column to datetimes - replace not necessary if specify format with `D` and `.` before `%f`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2022-12-01D07:52:52.04700000',
                           '2022-12-01D07:52:52.04700000']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S.%f')
print (df)
                     date
0 2022-12-01 07:52:52.047
1 2022-12-01 07:52:52.047
```

Answer (score 0):

> I realize I can replace the 'D' with 'T' but keeping the original form of the data is crucial for this piece of work.

Yes you can replace 'T' by 'D' with `str.replace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2022-12-01D07:52:52.04700000',
                           '2022-12-01T07:52:52.04700000',
                           '2022-12-01 07:52:52.04700000']})

df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace('D', 'T'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                           date                      dt
0  2022-12-01D07:52:52.04700000 2022-12-01 07:52:52.047
1  2022-12-01T07:52:52.04700000 2022-12-01 07:52:52.047
2  2022-12-01 07:52:52.04700000 2022-12-01 07:52:52.047
```

You can also use: `df['date'].str.replace('[A-Y]+', ' ', regex=True)`